# python how do i put a variable in command string

Tags: python, json

I'm new to python and cannot figure out how to do the following.
I want to put a variable inside a command but its not working. The command is taking the variable name not its value.

The script below calls https with username and password to get a token. I token is returned . I then need to use the token to create a user.
I'm having issues with it, "token" in the iplanet pair is not getting expanded correctly. It is set correctly as I can print it out before the command. So token would contain something like "AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcydd5smOKSGJT" , but when the 2nd http call is made it gets passed the word token , rather than tokens value.

```
    import requests
    import json

    url = "https://www.redacted.com:443/json/authenticate"

    headers = {
        'X-Username': "user",
        'X-Password': "password",
        'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
        }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)

    tokencreate = json.loads(response.text)
    token=tokencreate['tokenId']
    print token

    url = "https://www.redacted.com:443/json/users"

    querystring = {"_action":"create"}

    payload = "{\r\n\"username\":\"Patrick\",\r\n\"userpassword\":\"{{userpassword}}\",\r\n\"mail\":\"patrick@example.com\"\r\n}"
    headers = {
        'iPlanetDirectoryPro': "token",
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
        }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    print(response.text)
```

Comment: What do you mean "is not getting expanded correctly"?

Comment: I've update the question . token contains something like "AQIC5wM2LY4Sfcydd5smOKSGJTgfvMJSNtRL0NwU_iKoRg8.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABM3MTU4NzU5OTI5Mzk3MTA3ODEyAAJTMQACMDE.*" but the command is just being run with the word token not the string.

Comment: Try to change the line `'iPlanetDirectoryPro': "token",` to `'iPlanetDirectoryPro': token,` (remove quotation marks around `token`)

Comment: Cheers , thats fixed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are passing the ***string*** 'token' when you mean to pass the ***variable*** token

here you create the token:

```
tokencreate = json.loads(response.text)
token=tokencreate['tokenId']
print token
```

But you don't use the actual variable, it should look like this:

```
payload = "{\r\n\"username\":\"Patrick\",\r\n\"userpassword\":\"{{userpassword}}\",\r\n\"mail\":\"patrick@example.com\"\r\n}"
headers = {
    'iPlanetDirectoryPro': token,
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    }
```

Comment: Although if I wanted " " around the value would I have to use \" token \" ?

Comment: Not sure why you would do that, to cast it as a string? You can use string formating if the quotes are important, like this:
 
"'\"{}\"".format(token)

That will give you a string that is equal to "{the value of your token here}"